# C# Maui - How can i get a list of public files from File System

Tags: c#, android, maui

I need to be able to walk through the documents on an android phone using c# Maui.

This would be equilivant to the file picker, but i need to do it without user intervention.

I have tried the following strings in both Directory.GetDirectories(<string>, and Directory.GetFiles(<string>)

- /sdcard
- /data
- /internal storage
- /data

I have the following permissions setup in the platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: A summary of the ways to access files on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510403/199364. Sorry, accessing shared folders section lacks code.