# How to Modify Metadata of Media Files in Android 13 Given the Permissions Change

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, metadata, taglib

I was previously using TagLib to modify the metadata of my music files, and after updating to API 33, this code no longer works with permissions errors. I added the new permissions to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

It makes no difference, of course, because this is for reading the files. There doesn't appear to be any way to write to the files now, which means my app can no longer modify the metadata of my music files, which was the entire reason I built an app in the first place.

Does anyone know if there is some other way to do this? What an insane permission change. I can't find anything in a Google search on the subject. Thanks!

I tried changing the permissions to use the new granular permissions, but it didn't help, because they didn't add any granular permissions for writing to external storage.

Comment: You haven’t posted any code demonstrating what you’re trying to do, or provided any specific detail about the errors or exceptions you’re getting

Comment: None of that kind of information should be necessary to figuring out what to do about this problem. My code works perfectly fine, and the issue is that TagLib and as far as I can tell ANY metadata editor no longer has the ability to modify files found in Music or any /storage/emulated/0/ folders.

Comment: Because of permissions. The error is obviously "permissions denied".

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510403/199364), does this section and its linked doc help: *"For a shared directory, your app has to create an intent that asks user for permission to access the needed directory..."*? If you learn any additional info, please edit that "community wiki" answer.

Comment: If you write a new media file now (in a shared media folder), are you then able to restart your app, then modify that file? That is, is it only files written by older version of your app that get this permissions error? If so, treat it like a file written by another app: [Update other apps' media files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-other-apps-files): *"... You can get user consent to modify the file ... by catching the RecoverableSecurityException that the platform throws. ..."*

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, you quoted ok but the quote itself is nonsense as you can only let the user choose a directory. Which directory is up to the user. You cannot ask the user to give permissions for a certain directory. You get a SAF uri then. That SAF permission will not be usable to change meta data in MediaStore i think.

Comment: No that article is one I tried, and it still does not work on the newer versions. I posted the answer below, which I found out at like 2am after spending an embarrassing amount of time on this lol thanks for trying!!

Comment: @blackapps - Have you seen this? [Update other apps' media files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#update-other-apps-files) *"Optionally, you can specify the URI of the directory that the file picker should display when it first loads by using the EXTRA_INITIAL_URI intent extra."*

Comment: Yes we know that. But using that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add All Files access to apps within settings. In Android 13, open settings and then go to Security and Privacy > Privacy > Permission Manager > Files and Media > **See more apps that can access all files**.

If you turn on the switch for the app you are developing, it can continue to modify the metadata of music files in /storage/emulated/0/Music for instance.

I found this out by exploring the new permissions menus for hours, and I could not find a reference to this anywhere online. I was sure from their documentation of the latest release (API 33) that this was no longer possible. I hope this thread helps anyone else!

Comment: Nothing new using all files access. You only get this with using permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Which you did not tell us and which makes your app not suitable for play store.