# MAUI file picker returns a cached file address on android platform

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I use FilePicker to pick address of files that user selected but in android it seems copy the user selected files to cache folder and returns that copied files address.

```
 private async void bExecute_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilePickerFileType customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
        new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
                        { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.audio" } }, // UTType values
                        { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "audio/*" } }, // MIME type
                        { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".mp3", ".wav", ".wma", ".m4a", ".flac" } }, // file extension
                        { DevicePlatform.Tizen, new[] { "*/*" } },
                        { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { ".mp3", ".wav", ".wma", ".m4a", ".flac" } }, // UTType values
        });
        PickOptions options = new()
        {
            PickerTitle = "Please select audio file's",
            FileTypes = customFileType
        };

        var fileResult = await FilePicker.Default.PickMultipleAsync(options);

        // Let user pick files (and handling cancelling)
        foreach (FileResult file in fileResult)
        {
            var tfile = TagLib.File.Create(file.FullPath);
                  ...
        }
    }
```

it returns something like this on android
[Returned file location on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6fMK.png)
but in windows it works normally

Comment: Interesting. This might be a work-around to avoid problems people have had (on Android 13 | API 33), when use file path to a location not owned by the app. I'm a bit surprised, because my understanding is that once user has selected a file, that is put in app's list of files it has access to. See [wiki community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510403/199364) where I'm collecting what is known about Android file access,