# Why can apps like x-plore list all directories, while System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories gives access denied on Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Curiosity is killing me. In a test application for Android made with Xamarin and C#, I want to list all the files and directories in the path '/storage/emulated/0/Android'. I have already given the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, I am still getting access denied. Meanwhile, apps like X-plore can do it without problems, even though they have the same read and write permission...

Here is the code.

```
private void ListDaFiles(string rootDirectory)
{
    var paths = new List<string>();
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();

    RecursivelyListFilesAndDirectories(rootDirectory, fileList);

    foreach (string path in fileList)
    {
        paths.Add(path);
    }

}

private void RecursivelyListFilesAndDirectories(string directoryPath, List<string> fileList)
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
        string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);

        fileList.AddRange(files);

        foreach (string dir in directories)
        {
            fileList.Add(dir);
            RecursivelyListFilesAndDirectories(dir, fileList);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string err = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't ask for the permission at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution! In the AndroidManifest.xml file, I added the following:
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" inside 
although I had already done it before, what I did differently this time was to remove the permissions and uninstall the application. Then, I re-ran everything from scratch.
It worked wonders!

Comment: According to docs, that fix is OBSOLETE: You aren't targetting Android 13 (API 33) yet, are you? Or the device you are testing on isn't running Android 13. `requestLegacyExternalStorage` (allegedly) has no effect on new devices. According to docs, it stopped helping in Android 11 (API 30), though maybe it still had some benefit a bit longer. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

Comment: I'm running my code on Android 10.0 API 29.

Comment: That explains it. So be aware that this fix won't work in newer Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

> ... even though they have the same read and write permission

They presumably also [ask user for All Files Access](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access).

---

For other information about accessing files on newer Android version, see also [community wiki answer about Android file access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510403/199364).

Comment: Thank you for the response!, but it didn't work. I'm running my code on Android 10.0 API 29